# @Resource not injected in a JAX-WS SE that's a CDI managed-bean

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-ee-6, cdi

In a JAX-WS SE class I have a field in wich I inject a `@Resource` to finally get the client's IP address. All is ok until I make this SE a CDI managed bean

```
@WebService
public class AImpl implements A {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @Inject
    private ADelegated delegated;

        ...
}
```

I deploy this app in a WebLogic 12c and I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext field AImpl.wsContext to weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl
```

What is incorrect in my code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

JAX-WS doesn't have any CDI integration to my knowledge. What it seems like is happening is CDI is creating your bean instead of JAX-WS and the injections are getting mixed up.

Comment: says: "JAX-WS doesn't have any CDI integration to my knowledge" I don't think so... If JAX-WS doesn't work with CDI, the end comes in Dec-2012 as Mayas prediction !!! ;-) I'm currently working in a large project that's mixing JAX-WS with CDI. The problem started when I needed obtain the JAX-WS environment contexts to analyze request info.

Comment: Okay, great! I didn't know that it did. I didn't think there was an MR on the spec to include CDI... oh wait, the CDI spec had some specifics about JAX-WS, my bad :) Sorry, I just remembered.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution (with the help of Oracle forums people).

With the addition of the attribute 'name' to the @Resource annotation the problem was solved:

```
@WebService
public class AImpl implements A {

    @Resource(name="wsContext")
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @Inject
    private ADelegated delegated;

        ...
}
```

Comment: I tested the original app (without the 'name' attribute) in a JBoss-as-7.1.1.Final to appease-me, and it worked. So, it appears to be a WebLogic bug.